# Unable to download excel file from dropdown menu using material-ui and reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, download, dropdown

I'm trying to download file from public folder (**public/data/User.xlsx**) but I'm not able to download file. I'm using material-ui and react.js for this implementation

**component.js**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Button, Menu, MenuItem } from '@mui/material'
import isEmpty from 'lodash/fp/isEmpty'
import { styled, alpha } from '@mui/material/styles'
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown'

export default function CustomizedMenus(props) {
    const [ anchorEl, setAnchorEl ] = React.useState(null)
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl)

    const handleClick = React.useCallback(event => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
    }, [])
    const handleClose = React.useCallback((hRef, fileName) => {
        if (!isEmpty(hRef) && !isEmpty(fileName) && fileName !== 'backdropClick') {
            const link = document.createElement('a')
            link.download = fileName
            link.href = hRef
            link.click()
        }
        setAnchorEl(null)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <Button
                id='customized-button'
                aria-controls={open ? 'customized-menu' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup='true'
                aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                variant='contained'
                disableElevation
                onClick={handleClick}
                endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            >
                Download Template Header
            </Button>
            <Menu
                id='customized-menu'
                MenuListProps={{
                    'aria-labelledby': 'customized-button',
                }}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
            >
                <MenuItem onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose('/data/User.xlsx', 'User'))} disableRipple>User</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose('/data/Employee.xlsx', 'Employee'))} disableRipple>Employee</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added file extension to the file name it working as I expected way

**Error:**

```
<MenuItem onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose('/data/User.xlsx', 'User'))} disableRipple>User</MenuItem>
<MenuItem onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose('/data/Employee.xlsx', 'Employee'))} disableRipple>Employee</MenuItem>
```

**Solution:**

```
<MenuItem onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose('/data/User.xlsx', 'User.xlsx'))} disableRipple>User</MenuItem>
<MenuItem onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose('/data/Employee.xlsx', 'Employee.xlsx'))} disableRipple>Employee</MenuItem>
```